# How to use custom variables in phtml file for email

Tags: magento-1.9, transactional-mail, custom-variable

I have created a **Transactional Emails template** in magento admin to send multiple coupon codes dynamically for this I have created a template file says `email/custom.phtml` and it is included in email template.

It is included in email template successfully but I am trying to add `{{var code12}}`, `{{ var code13 }}` etc. with multiple time but it is not working.

If I add these in direct email template in magento admin then it is working as I want but I want to create `{{var}}` also dynamically.

I am using below code for sending email :

```
$senderName = 'custom';
$senderEmail = Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_general/email');

$emailTemplate = Mage::getModel('core/email_template')->loadByCode('Custom Template');;
$emailTemplateVariables = array();
$emailTemplateVariables['name'] = 'name';
$emailTemplateVariables['code12'] = 'AB56FFD';
$processedTemplate = $emailTemplate->getProcessedTemplate($emailTemplateVariables);
$mail = Mage::getModel('core/email')
        ->setToName('name')
        ->setToEmail('test@gmail.com')
        ->setBody($processedTemplate)
        ->setSubject('Coupon code')
        ->setFromEmail($senderEmail)
        ->setFromName($senderName)
        ->setType('html');
$mail->send();
```

My `custom.phtml` code is here :

```
##My shopping cart rule are product specific
<table>
<?php 
$allProducts = array(10,20,30);
foreach($allProducts as $product_id)
{
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);
    ?>
    <tr><td>
    <?php
    echo $product->getName();
    echo Mage::getModel('core/variable')->loadByCode('code12')->getValue('text');  // it is not working
    ?>
    {{var code12}}  // it is not working
    </td></tr>
    <?php
}
?>
</table>
```

And **Transactional Emails template** code is here :

```
...
{{block type="core/template"  name="email_custom" template="email/custom.phtml" }}
....
```

How to add `custom variables` in phtml file?

Comment: sorry don't understand you want to add phml file in email template or pass multiple variable to email template

Comment: check : http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2011/11/25/magento-advanced-transactional-email-templates/

Comment: Yes I want to send multiple coupon code to one customer and for this calculation I have created a custom.phtml file which is included in email template. In event observer I generated code dynamically and saved to shopping cart rule. and at the time of email sending wants to send those code.

Comment: Hello @NikunjPatel, Can you explain link provided by you?

Comment: kindly add the phtml and  email template code too.

Comment: Please check my updated question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pass a array

```
$emailTemplateVariables['code'] = array('code12'=>'AB56FFD','code13'=>'AB5fd6FFD','code14'=>'AB56dfFFD') ;
```

you have to pass variable to phtml file

```
{{block type="core/template"  name="email_custom" template="email/custom.phtml" code=$code}}
```

in phtml file

```
$code= $this->getCode();
echo $code['code12'];
```

Comment: It will work with multiple variable? like `{{block type="core/template"  name="email_custom" template="email/custom.phtml" code12=$code12 code10=$code10}}`

Comment: yes it will work but it is better to pass array.

Comment: How to pass array?

Comment: @VinayaMaheshwari updated the code

Comment: Hello @QaisarSatti, When I am using `$code= $this->code()` then an empty  email received?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer but `$code= $this->getCode();` working instead of `$code= $this->code();`.