# how to pass a custom variable from phtml file to email template

Tags: magento-1.9, email-templates, phtml, variables

I am stuck in my custom code.

I want to pass a custom variable from **phtml** file to template.

I have added my template in email template:

```
{{block type='core/template' area='frontend' template='order-approval/item.phml'}}
```

but how to pass variable of this page

Comment: show some code and give an example.

Comment: i want to pass this variable   <?php
   $postData['message'];
  $postData = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
   echo '<pre>';
   print_r($postData);
 
   ?>

Comment: follow http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/141586/how-to-use-custom-variables-in-phtml-file-for-email?rq=1

Comment: its not working for me